# pylint warning - unsubscriptable-object

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

with the below code snipped in visual studio code editor

```
a = b.get('c') if b else None
d = a[1] if a else None
```

`pylint` is giving the following warning in the second line for `a[1]`.Is it correct to show the warning? Shouldn't the check for `None` cover it ?

```
a: NoneType
Value 'a' is unsubscriptable pylint(unsubscriptable-object)
```

Comment: This is fine, the linter is not smart enough to detect None check. Explicit check (`if a is not None: ...`) might fix this, otherwise it's better to add an exception or simply ignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pylint](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/) is either not detecting the right type, and you can suppress the warning via:

```
d = a[1] if a else None  # pylint: disable=unsubscriptable-object
```

or (since var b isn't in your post), it's correct, and `b.get('c')` returns an unsubscriptable type, for example:

```
b = {"c": 1}
a = b.get('c') if b else None
# a = 1, 1 is not subscriptable
```

Comment: It is one of many pylint warnings that makes dumb (given that it is python) assumptions and often has to be disabled.

This is the problem of "opinionated" software: it is often parochial and doesn't work correctly in other contexts.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment and the edit queue is full so a quick note on Jay Moody's response.

The answer is correct, but it needs a tweak (at least for me). The statement`# pylint disable=unsubscriptable-object` needs a colon after pylint.

What works for me is `# pylint: disable=unsubscriptable-object`.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in older versions of pylint. It looks like it was fixed somewhere around version 2.7.0 by [this PR](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/pull/3890).

Comment: I’m still seeing this problem with v3.0.3 on a `sessionmaker[Session]` return type hint, where [sessionmaker](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/1669ae65da251bfe7c8afb9b6a983bec81e8ac1b/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py#L4889) is a SQLA class inheriting from a Generic. There are several [open issues](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+object+unsubscriptable+) on that topic, though…